# Cannot install Emmet for Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++, emmet

After I downloaded Notepad++, I installed [Plugin Manager](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager) and tried to install Emmet. Only "Installation of Emmet failed" I saw after that. I've tried everything. Install different versions of Notepad++ (including x86) and Python Script. Tried to install it manually. Nothing worked.

How can I install Emmet on Nodepad++?

UPD: I have deleted everything from APPDATA and used "Programms and Components" to uninstall Notepad++

Answer (score 3):

Emmet doesn't show up on Notepad++ Plugin Manager window. Maybe it's outdated or not compatible anymore. Anyway, when you manually install Emmet and you still can't see the plugin please follow those steps;

- Open Notepad++ and install **Python Script** plugin (available in Plugin Manager)
- Then [open plugins folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f87Za.png) from Plugins menu and extract [emmet-npp.zip](http://download.emmet.io/npp/emmet-npp.zip) into *plugins* folder.

**Note**: If it doesn't work, you might need to move **EmmetNPP.dll** file inside *EmmetNPP* folder.

Now restart Notepad++ and you should see the Emmet plugin in your Plugins menu.

Comment: Windows 10 can't safely download the zip file. It reads the file may be dangerous. Even if I download I can't unzip it for the same reason. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the "EmmetNPP.dll" file into the "EmmetNPP" plugin folder, after having extracted both files into the plugins folder in Notepad++. The official GitHub site missed out this step.

Answer (score 0):

I did all of the following to get it working. One or two of these steps might not be required, but after the final step it started working *(i.e. it appeared on the Plugins menu without needing to install via Plugins Admin, and Emmet functions correctly via the Plugins -> Emmet dropdown menu. Next step is to setup keyboard shortcuts (i.e. Tab) as described elsewhere)*.

1. Plugins Admin -> install Python Script (restart NPP)
2. Download and extract the NPP plugin from https://emmet.io/download/
3. Copy the extracted `EmmetNPP.dll` and the `EmmetNPP` folder into:
   `%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config` folder
4. Copy file `EmmetNPP.dll` file into:
   `%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config\EmmetNPP` folder
5. Copy file `EmmetNPP.dll` file into:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\EmmetNPP` folder

Notes:

a. I am using the 32-bit version of NPP; if you are using the 64-bit version then step 5 should copy the `EmmetNPP.dll` file into:
`C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\EmmetNPP` folder

b. After step 4, Emmet still did not appear either in the Plugins dropdown OR in the Plugin Admin tool. After step 5, though, it now appears in the Plugins dropdown and is functional. *(Note that I was careful to restart NPP after each of the above steps. Future readers will not need to restart after each step (just keep NPP closed for steps 2-5) - I did so to test at what point it started working.)*

Answer (score -1):

Emmet is installed on Notepad++ using the plugin manager (full instructions found on [Emmet for Notepad++ GitHub repo](https://github.com/emmetio/npp#installation)). If you have installed a clean Notepad++ (latest version) and have installed the Notepad++ plugin manager, use `Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager` menu action and find and install “Emmet” plugin.

If this isn't working for you, the first thing I would do is uninstall Notepad++ and all extensions/modifications you've added to it and start fresh:

1. Install Notepad++
2. Install Nodepad++ Plugin Manger
3. Install Emmet **from the Plugin Manager menu**

Comment: I have already done everything you wrote about. When I try to install Emmet, I have a message about error. But thanks for attempt to help

Comment: It's absent in plugin manager. Notepad++ 8.1.4